# "prove to be painful" vs "prove painful", any difference?

Tags: linking-verbs

What should I put here, "The learning process **proved to be painful** or just The learning process **proved painful**" ? Is there any difference ?

[image: proved to be painful]

BTW, the question is to fill in the blank with the **correct form** of the word given.

As @MarcInManhattan pointed out, ["To be" in front of adjective?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/266672/to-be-in-front-of-adjective) may have answered my question, i.e. "to be" here is optional, so these two forms are the same.

Can someone confirm that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["To be" in front of adjective?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/266672/to-be-in-front-of-adjective)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan were you suggesting adding "to be" here is optional, i.e. "proved to be painful" is the same as "proved painful" here?

Comment: I am suggesting that the other question discusses "to be [adjective]" vs. "[adjective]". If you believe that this question is actually asking something different than that one, then please explain why. (It may also help to do more searching on ELL, because this is not an uncommon issue.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan the thing is I am not sure if my question was the same as the one you point out, i.e. I am not sure if **to be** here is optional, so the meaning of "proved to be painful" is the same as "proved painful" (it looks like that). So if it is the same, please let me know.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I have updated the question.